# Script works fine while execute, but won't run from cronjob

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, vlc-media-player, crontab

I have a script called "record.sh"
It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/vlc -vvv rtsp://admin:blablabla@192.168.2.20:554/ch0_0.h264 --sout=file/ts:Videos/VideoCaptures/recording-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").mp4 -I dummy --stop-time=3600 vlc://quit
exit
```

Also make it executable with: `chmod +x record.sh`

Now the real question.
When I double click on the script, it executes fine!
But when I make an cronjob (crontab -e)

```
*/60 * * * * /home/pi/record.sh
```

it will not run at all.

Even the following cronjob won't work;

```
*/60 * * * * /usr/bin/vlc -vvv rtsp://admin:blablabla@192.168.2.20:554/ch0_0.h264 --sout=file/ts:Videos/VideoCaptures/recording-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").mp4 -I dummy --stop-time=3600 vlc://quit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it fails, either you or root should get an email telling you why it failed. As a first step, I would do something like `* * * * * touch /tmp/does_this_work` and see if it is created. I would expect though, vlc requires a display, and one is not available through cron  by default.

Comment: This is working

Comment: Then I would assume vlc requires a display, and will fail without one.

Answer (score 1):

`--sout=file/ts:Videos/...` -- presumably, the Videos directory is in your home directory. cron's current directory is `/`. You'll need

```
--sout=file/ts:$HOME/Videos/...
```

Additionally, percent signs are special in crontabs and need to be escaped:

```
recording-$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S").mp4
```

Check your `crontab(5)` man page.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Changed al you suggested.
unfortunately still not working :(

Comment: Seems like @Bib is right, vlc needs a display. There is "headless" display emulators you can use, but the name escapes me at the moment.

Comment: I found this solution, but it isn't also working: 
https://xrunhprof.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/using-vlc-and-cron-to-record-a-stream/